# How to remove object from item array of dojo store

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dojo

I have an ordered store in which I'm using for a filtering-select, I need to remove an item from the store, How to do that knowing that
The object in the array has only two attributes VALUE and LABEL,

The store is like :

```
{
    "items":
        [
            {
                "VALUE":"AG",
                "LABEL":"Agriculture"
            },
            {
                "VALUE":"CE",
                "LABEL":"Construction"
            },
            {
                "VALUE":"CO",
                "LABEL":"Consumer"
            }
        ],
    "identifier":"VALUE"
}
```

And I want to remove one of the objects in the items Array.

Comment: is there any way to do this using dojo

Answer (score 2):

There are serveral ways to delete an obj from array and its  quiet simple by example:

1. ## Native JS

**Using Array.splice:**

```js
var json = {"items":[{"VALUE":"AG","LABEL":"Agriculture"},{"VALUE":"CE","LABEL":"Construction"},{"VALUE":"CO","LABEL":"Consumer"},
{"VALUE":"CD","LABEL":"CDsample"},
{"VALUE":"AL","LABEL":"Aluminium"}],"identifier":"VALUE"}

var array = json.items;
var valueToRemove = "CD";

json.items.forEach(function(element,index){
  if(element["VALUE"] == valueToRemove)
    json.items.splice(index, 1);
});

console.log(json);
```

**Using Array.filter**

```js
var json = {"items":[{"VALUE":"AG","LABEL":"Agriculture"},{"VALUE":"CE","LABEL":"Construction"},{"VALUE":"CO","LABEL":"Consumer"},
    {"VALUE":"CD","LABEL":"CDsample"},
    {"VALUE":"AL","LABEL":"Aluminium"}],"identifier":"VALUE"}
//get the array from
var array = json.items;
var valueToRemove = "CD";
json.items = json.items.filter(function(element) {
    return element["VALUE"] !== valueToRemove;
});

console.log(json);
```

2. ## Using Dojo

***Using Array.map :***

```js
require(["dojo/_base/array"],function(Array){
  var json = {"items":[{"VALUE":"AG","LABEL":"Agriculture"},{"VALUE":"CE","LABEL":"Construction"},{"VALUE":"CO","LABEL":"Consumer"},
  {"VALUE":"CD","LABEL":"CDsample"}, {"VALUE":"AL","LABEL":"Aluminium"}],"identifier":"VALUE"};


  var valueToRemove = "CD";
  //get index of element
  var index = Array.map(json.items, function(item){
    return item["VALUE"];
  }).indexOf(valueToRemove);
  //remove elemnt at that index
  json.items.splice(index,1);

  console.log(json);
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

***Using Array.filter :***

```js
require(["dojo/_base/array"],function(Array){
  var json = {"items":[{"VALUE":"AG","LABEL":"Agriculture"},{"VALUE":"CE","LABEL":"Construction"},{"VALUE":"CO","LABEL":"Consumer"},
  {"VALUE":"CD","LABEL":"CDsample"}, {"VALUE":"AL","LABEL":"Aluminium"}],"identifier":"VALUE"};


  var valueToRemove = "CD";
 
 //filter
  json.items = Array.filter(json.items, function(item){
    return item["VALUE"] != valueToRemove;
  });

  console.log(json);
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

***Using Array.forEach :***

```js
require(["dojo/_base/array"],function(Array){
  var json = {"items":[{"VALUE":"AG","LABEL":"Agriculture"},{"VALUE":"CE","LABEL":"Construction"},{"VALUE":"CO","LABEL":"Consumer"},
  {"VALUE":"CD","LABEL":"CDsample"}, {"VALUE":"AL","LABEL":"Aluminium"}],"identifier":"VALUE"};


  var valueToRemove = "CD";


  Array.forEach(json.items, function(item,index){
    if(item)
      if(item["VALUE"] == valueToRemove)
        json.items.splice(index,1);

  });

  console.log(json);
})
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: @nithinalways I've added mutltiple sample , using js and also Dojo ,
hope this will help you , if that please mark the answer as resolved :)